# How to avoid a directory from being removed

Tags: git, directory, rm

I wanted to know if there is a way to create a file inside a directory that avoids it to be removed by a simple `rm -r`, just like when we have a Git respository and it is not deleted because of the `.git` file.

Comment: Please may you explain? _"just like when we have a git respository and it is not deleted because of the .git file"_ doesn't make sense. If I run `rm -r .git` _it will remove_ the repo

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, such a feature does not exist natively.

The convention is to add a `.keep` dummy file in a folder you want to include n your git repository (especially if this folder starts empty, since Git does not version empty directory).

But nothing would prevent an OS command (like rm/del/delete) to actually delete the folder, and Git to detect that deletion in its status.